# fail to remote debug tomcat with eclipse after deploy a modified jar

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging, geoserver

I'm developing a datastore plugin to `Geoserver`, to develop it faster I am trying to remote debug it. `Geoserver` uses `Tomcat` behind the curtains. I prepared everything to remote debug via `Eclipse` and accomplished it. Now I can remote debug my plugin. However, when I modify my code (I tried to add a harmless line like: `int noHarm = 5;`) and then export it as jar and copy that jar to `webapps\lib\` under `Geoserver` installation directory, I fail to remote debug the plugin. After that I changed that modification back to when it was worked(deleted `int noHarm = 5;`) and created the jar again, then copied it under `webapps\lib\` , now I am able to remote debug again.

When I open stores page in `Geoserver`, it stops at breakpoints in the `canProcess()` method with the jar exported from not modified code or when I try to add new Store it stops at breakpoints in the `createDataStore()` method with the jar exported from not modified code. But if I change even a tiny line or add it won't stop at breakpoints even though it connects to virtual host succesfully(I use `vmware workstation` with windows 7-32 bit on it if it helps).

What could be the problem?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: after changes to make effect restart the server, and you can debug again.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but I am already doing that. Actually I am forced to do that because I can't delete old jar file if I don't stop geoserver. After restarting Geoserver I also reconnect to virtual host via Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was about `eclipse`. My source files was not in the workspace so, in the project `build path --> under the source tab` I was using `Link Source` button. That button allows you to link java files (which are not under your workspace) to your project and let those files act as source. What I did to solve this problem:

- I then moved those files under project's real source folder
- With that I created jar.
- I stopped Geoserver(Tomcat) and copied my jar under webapps\lib\
- I started Geoserver(Tomcat) and connected to server via eclipse remote debug.

After these steps I was able to remote debug with every jar I deployed.